# How do I remove the bash from systemd service file? and replace it with something that solves my problem explained below?

Tags: bash, spring-boot, systemd, exit-code

Boring details alert:
I have a `systemd` `service` file which uses a bash file to start the service. Below is the service file in question:

```
[Unit]
Description=A program service
[Service]
User=root
#change this to your workspace
WorkingDirectory=/data/acloud/repository/lib
#path to executable. 
#executable is a bash script file I created to run the application jar file
ExecStart=/data/acloud/repository/lib/program.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Below is `program.sh` I used in the service file above:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo java -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx1g -Xms512m -jar abc-program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

If you are wondering why I created a single line bash script, its because I do not know where and how to put the *-XX, -Xms -Xmx* parameters in `.service` file.

Even when the service is inactive, Main PID status is shown as `status=0/SUCCESS` and at the end of the `systemctl status` command output, it says `Started a program service`?? Below is how its shown:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-**-**-***:/data/acloud/repository/lib$ sudo systemctl status program
program.service - A program service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/program.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2019-02-22 13:08:21 UTC; 45s ago
  Process: 27711 ExecStart=/data/acloud/repository/lib/program.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 27711 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 22 13:08:21 ip-172-**-**-*** systemd[1]: Started A program service.
```

I believe that using bash is causing this problem as the exit codes are not manipulated in here. How do I get this to stop?

Comment: duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/1120576/10127

Comment: You might try `exec sudo java ...` which will cause the sudo process to *replace* the shell process. I imagine sudo does the same thing with java, but I'm not sure about that.